# Wordpress Authors that are not users

Tags: wordpress

Whats a smart way to create a list of authors with their respective articles without creating new users for each one?

Each author could have many articles and each article could have many authors.

I know how this works in a custom relational db but I am not sure how it would work best with the WP DP.

A combination of Custom post types and custom fields I presume?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off making them users with the author role. It will save you a lot of work.

That said, I would probably tag the posts with a custom field (post meta). Then you could retrieve those with `get_posts` since you can query by meta:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'authorname',
            'value' => 'steve',
        )
    )
 );
$postsbyauthor = get_posts( $args );
```

If you did use a custom post type, you could add that to your query arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'guestpost'
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'authorname',
            'value' => 'steve',
        )
    )
 );
$postsbyauthor = get_posts( $args );
```